# JRules 7.0 to Drools 6.2 Migration

Tags: drools, jrules

Can someone please share your idea on the following..?

1. What is the best possible way to migrate rules from ILOG JRules 7.0 to Drools 6.2? Please share some examples.
   We have about 5000 rules in JRules written using action rules and decision tables.
2. Is there a way to create user-defined / custom functions / methods and use them in rules directly?

Thanks and regards,
Amlan

Comment: 1. Find and hire an expert knowing both systems well. 2. Yes.

Comment: Anyone with any inputs please...?